# How to Display Data from Existing List via Criteria in Orchard

Tags: razor, orchardcms

In Orchard, I have a News Article List, each News Article item has a flag to say it's 'archived'. Archived Articles do not show in the News Article List but are still published and I want to show the 'archived' Articles in a another List named News Article Archives.

Is there a way for me to display data from a single list differently between two List Content Types without re-assigning the News Articles to be under one or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The List feature is only made to represent container-containee relationships, and an item can have only one container. What you need to implement your scenario is either a custom query in a custom controller (that works today), or a custom query in Projector (a new module that will be included in the next version).

Comment: Thanks for the help. If it's not much trouble are there any examples online for the 'custom query in a custom controller' you suggested?

Comment: Look through the code of the core modules for many many examples of that. Orchard.Tags/Controllers/HomeController is one.